# How do I compare two files and output what is the same in a new file with python

Tags: python

I need it to be case insensitive.
Here is what I have so far which seems to work, but I can't get it to be case insensitive. One file is uppercase and one is lowercase.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as new_file:
    for line in same:
        new_file.write(line)
```

if i had two files containing “ 123:hereisanexample” and “HEREISANEXAMPLE” i would want “hereisanexample” to be put in the output file.

I added:

```
for line in file1:
    file1 = line.split(':')
for line in file2:
    file2 = line.split(':')
```

But thats not working

Comment: maybe store it in a variable and then make it all lowercase or uppercase then compare

Comment: You can user ```.lower()``` to convert the file strings to be the same and then compare them

Comment: Where would i put the .lower()? Ive tried a couple variations and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the same"? Does the position matter? For example if the word "dog" appears in both the files, but in different locations, would that count? What about words inside of other words (like "click" and "lick"), do those count?

Comment: So the words can appear in different locations but not inside other words. Here is an example: if i had “ 123:hereisanexample” and “HEREISANEXAMPLE” i would want “hereisanexample” to be put in the output file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading from the file you can convert it into lower case and then split it according to the newline character. This code should work, but it has some limitations because of the 'set' duplicate lines would be ignored and order would not be preserved. This is just to give you a small idea.

```
file1 = set(open('1.txt').read().lower().splitlines())
file2 = set(open('2.txt').read().lower().splitlines())

same = file1.intersection(file2)

with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as new_file:
    for line in same:
        new_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: This works! Is there a way to have the output on separate lines? It currently all prints on one line.

Comment: @rocotyco You can add a new line character after every line. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: I added a part to my question about using split, let me know if this is doable and if you have any ideas. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this...

this is the file I used as an example "**example_file.txt**":

> IN THe UNItED stATes, i'm OfTeN BOMbArDED wITh imageS ANd ADs oF FiTneSs CuLturE. atHlEisuRE Is the craZE, anD IT sEEmS THAt THE MajorItY Of PEOPLe ARE MemBErS oF gymS LiKe ANYTime FItNESs, 24 hoUr FiTnESs, Or la FiTNESs. ANy DEceNt HoTel oR tYpIcAl ...

this is the python code:

```
file = open('text.txt')

print((file.read()).lower())
```

the result should be : "in the united states, i'm often bombarded with images and ads of fitness culture. athleisure is the craze, and it seems that the majority of people are members of gyms like anytime fitness, 24 hour fitness, or la fitness. any decent hotel or typical ..."

To convert a string to lower case, use the lower() method. lower() returns a copy of the string in lower case.

with this example you can convert everything to lowercase and thus compare if that's what you need

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now, would i be able to make it so if i had “ 123:hereisanexample” and “hereisanexample” i would want “hereisanexample” to be put in the output file? I think i can do this with split or stirp but am unsure how.

Comment: if the text would be something like: "123:hereisanexample" you would only have to do the following: "123:hereisanexample".split(':')[1] the output would be: hereisanexample

Answer (score 0):

A normal comparison operator works just fine.

```
text = open("text.txt", "r").read()
text2 = open("text2.txt", "r").read()

if text.lower() == text2.lower():
    print(True)

else:
    False

If you want the word example without the colon you should do this

import re

for file_name in ("text.txt", "text2.txt"):
    with open(file_name, "r") as fl:
        # '\s' checks if there is a word with a space before it
        texts = re.findall(r"\sexample", fl.read())
        print(texts)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how I could split things so if one file contains "123:example" and another contains "example", "example" would be printed in the output?